# Perform Instrumentation Testing of SyncAdapter

Tags: android, junit, android-syncadapter, android-junit

How does one go about testing a SyncAdapter? I am talking about test methods that verify that `onPerformSync` is called with the correct parameters and `extras` and that it responds as expected, etc. etc. The platform seems to provide instrumentation classes for ContentProvider, Activity, etc. But how do I write instrumentation test my SyncAdapter?

Comment: Did you happen to find an answer to this? I'm dealing with the same issue